# pictures or camera browser

Tags: android

I'm trying to do the next:
I have an ImageView and i want it to appears a pictures browser or camera when user touchs it to let him select or take a picture.
I've found that:

```
private void openPictureBrowser()
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,"A Custom Title"); //optional
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS); //optional
   try {
      startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   switch (requestCode) {
      case 1: {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            String filePath = data.getData().getPath(); //WARNING: this is NOT your real path (in my case, value is set to "/external/images/media/4"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What can i do in openPictureBrowser if I want to add the camera?

And what should I do in onActivityResult to set filePath as ImageView background?

Can anybody give me a hint??

Thanxs!

Comment: So, you want to let the user to choose an image from either the gallery or the camera and then (obviously) display the result in an ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Set_image extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    Button btn_capture_image,btn_share_from_gallery;
    ImageView iv_set_image;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
     private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    String filePath="";
    Bitmap Main_bitmap;


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.set_image);

        btn_capture_image =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture_image);
        btn_share_from_gallery =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_share_from_gallery);
        iv_set_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_set_iamge);

        btn_capture_image.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_share_from_gallery.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


public void onClick(View v) 
{

        if (v == btn_capture_image)
        {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }


        if (v == btn_share_from_gallery)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)
        {  
            Main_bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
            iv_set_image.setImageBitmap(Main_bitmap);    
        }   

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)

            try 
             {

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

              if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
              {
                     int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                     filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                     BitmapFactory.Options options4 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                     options4.inSampleSize = 1;
                     Main_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options4);                         iv_set_image.setImageBitmap(Main_bitmap);


               }
                    cursor.close();
             } 
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanx you, I'm going to try it

Answer (score -1):

use the following code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoadImage extends Activity 
{
    Activity activity=null;
    Context context=null;

    Button header_left_btn=null;
    Button header_right_btn=null;
    TextView header_text=null;
    TableLayout image_table=null;

    ArrayList<String> image_list=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Drawable> image_drawable=new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    String path="";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.header);

        activity=LoadImage.this;
        context=LoadImage.this;

        header_left_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.header_left_btn);
        header_right_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.header_right_btn);
        header_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_text);
        image_table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.image_table);

        header_text.setText("Image Table");
        header_left_btn.setText("Select");
        header_right_btn.setText("Clear");
        registerForContextMenu(header_left_btn);

        header_left_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                openContextMenu(header_left_btn);
            }
        });

        header_right_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                image_list.clear();
                image_drawable.clear();
                deletePhotos();
                updateImageTable();
            }
        });
    }

    public void deletePhotos()
    {
        String folder=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/LoadImg";
        File f=new File(folder);
        if(f.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files=f.listFiles();
            Log.v("Load Image", "Total Files To Delete=====>>>>>"+files.length);
            for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
            {
                String fpath=folder+File.separator+files[i].getName().toString().trim();
                System.out.println("File Full Path======>>>"+fpath);
                File nf=new File(fpath);
                if(nf.exists())
                {
                    nf.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Post Image");
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.camer_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
          case R.id.take_photo:
              //Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Take Photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              takePhoto();
              break;

          case R.id.choose_gallery:
              //Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
              photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
              startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

              break;

          case R.id.share_cancel:
              closeContextMenu();
              break;
          default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
      }
      return true;
    }

    public void takePhoto() 
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
         File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/LoadImg");

         if(!folder.exists())
         {
             folder.mkdir();
         }         
         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         String new_Date= c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+((c.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1)   +"-"+c.get(Calendar.YEAR) +" " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+ "-"+ c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
         path=String.format(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/LoadImg/%s.png","LoadImg("+new_Date+")");
         File photo = new File(path); 
         intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photo));
         startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==1)
        {
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            if (photoUri != null)
            {
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Log.v("Load Image", "Gallery File Path=====>>>"+filePath);
                image_list.add(filePath);
                Log.v("Load Image", "Image List Size=====>>>"+image_list.size());

                //updateImageTable();
                new GetImages().execute();
            }
        }

        if(requestCode==2)
        {
            Log.v("Load Image", "Camera File Path=====>>>"+path);
            image_list.add(path);
             Log.v("Load Image", "Image List Size=====>>>"+image_list.size());
            //updateImageTable();
             new GetImages().execute();
        }
    }

    public void updateImageTable()
    {
        image_table.removeAllViews();

        if(image_drawable.size() > 0)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<image_drawable.size(); i++)
            {
                TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                tableRow.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
                {
                    ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
                    image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    /*Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_list.get(i).toString().trim());
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,500, 500, true);
                    Drawable d=loadImagefromurl(bitmap);*/
                    image.setBackgroundDrawable(image_drawable.get(i));

                    tableRow.addView(image, 200, 200);
                }
                image_table.addView(tableRow);
            }
        }
    }

    public Drawable loadImagefromurl(Bitmap icon)
    {
        Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(icon);        
        return d;
    }

    public class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
    {
        public ProgressDialog progDialog=null;

        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            progDialog=ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...",true);
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            image_drawable.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<image_list.size(); i++)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_list.get(i).toString().trim());
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,500, 500, true);
                Drawable d=loadImagefromurl(bitmap);

                image_drawable.add(d);
            }
            return null;
        }    

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            if(progDialog.isShowing())
            {
                progDialog.dismiss();
            }
            updateImageTable();
        }
    }
}
```

i have got this code from following link :
http://tjkannan.blogspot.in/2012/01/load-image-from-camera-or-gallery.html

Hope this will help you .